# How do you create a triggerer process in an Airflow installation?

Tags: airflow

In an Airflow DAG, I am trying to use a TimeDeltaTrigger:

```
from airflow.triggers.temporal import TimeDeltaTrigger
...
self.defer(trigger=TimeDeltaTrigger(timedelta(seconds=15)), method_name="execute")
```

But when my DAG runs, I get a warning in the GUI:

[image]

In the GUI, if I go to Browse -> Triggers I see one trigger, but it is not for `TimeDeltaTrigger`:

[image]

The documentation for Deferrable Operators (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/deferring.html) says:

> Ensure your Airflow installation is running at least one triggerer process, as well as the normal scheduler

But it is not clear how to do this.

How can I configure my Airflow installation so that I can use a `TimeDeltaTrigger`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`triggerer` is a process like `scheduler`, `webserver`, and `worker`. You need to start a process or container dedicated to running the triggerer to use deferrable operators.

To start a triggerer process, run `airflow triggerer` in your Airflow environment. You should see an output similar to the below image.

Triggerer Logs
[image]

Comment: `airflow scheduler` is already a cpu hog, i hope `airflow triggerer` is not :)